# Iterating Rows for Different Columns with Python and Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl, worksheet

I'm trying to iterate through rows in an Excel spreadsheet using openpyxl.
What I'm trying to do is check if the cell in column A is empty for the current row, and if it is, I need to print the data that is in column B on that same row.
Here is my code so far:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('worksheet.xlsx')
wb.active = 1 #Change the active sheet.
sheets = wb.sheetnames #The sheets.
currentSheet = wb[sheets[n]] #Chooses the current sheet from the workbook.

for row in currentSheet.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(currentSheet.min_row, currentSheet.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        if not cell.value:
            print(currentSheet['B''row'].value)
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
  File "main.py", line 69, in get_callout
    print(currentSheet['B''row'].value)
  File "C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ope
pyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 357, in __getitem__
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
  File "C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ope
pyxl\utils\cell.py", line 135, in range_boundaries
    raise ValueError("{0} is not a valid coordinate or range")
ValueError: {0} is not a valid coordinate or range
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that I'm also using openpyxl 2.4.9 because 2.5.3 (the current version) won't let me open the Excel workbook that I need to use.

Comment: 'row' should be `row` the variable? and concatenated with string 'B' like `'B'+row` ?

Comment: If you're talking about the 'row' in the print statement, then yes that is the `row` variable. I just tried concatenating it by doing `print(currentSheet['B'+row].value)` but that also doesn't work, however I think you're on the right track.

Comment: `print("{}{}".format('B', row))`

Comment: Doing that prints out the following: `B(<Cell 'SHEET 1'.A1>,)` for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a different way of doing it!

Here is my code for anybody that might stumble upon this in the future:

```
    for r in range(1, currentSheet.max_row):
        cell = currentSheet.cell(row=r, column=12)
        if cell.value is None:
            data = currentSheet.cell(row=r, column=2)
            print(data.value)
```

Basically what I was doing was checking to see if column L (12) was empty, and if it was I needed to print the value on the same row but in column B (2). Printing can obviously be changed with anything else (return or something else).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of when you should using Excel notation.

```
for (a, b) in currentSheet.iter_rows(max_col=2):
   if a.value is None:
       print(b.value)
```

Should work

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for the reply! I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 71, in get_callout
    for (a, b) in currentSheet(max_col=2):
TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable`

Comment: Also I'm now trying to read if column L is empty instead of column A, but I'm guessing that won't change much of the code.